# Do I need an OAuth server implementation for a web application with a login system?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, oauth

If I'm creating a web application with a RESTful back end, is OAuth 2.0 really necessary given that I don't want to connect with social media (Facebook, Google+, etc.)? I'm thinking about ditching OAuth2.0 and doing the following:

- Generate JWT tokens upon successful login
- Store this token in redis (or database, haven't decided)
- Have a filter that checks for the JWT token and matches the token with the one in redis/db.
- If the token exists, allow the user to access the resource

Comment: You can use a service like https://auth0.com/ which will act as your authentication server will return you a JWT. The beauty of JWT is that you can then use them directly and use the `.sub` claim to map to user. Then you can have social signup optionally (and Auth0 will handle it for you overall helping you deploy in minutes) (Disclosure: I work for Auth0)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually generate JWT tokens if you wish but it would be better to let an oAuth 2.0 implementation handle the JWT generation.

You don't need to persist the token. Just check the signed signature of the JWT, there is no need to check a database as the point of a JWT is for stateless authentication.

Comment: So I should still implement my own OAuth2 server then but use JWT tokens? And you recommend keeping the tokens in memory for authentication? If I don't store the tokens somehow on the server (in memory, cache, or db), then how will I know what user has which token? That means user A could access user B's data?

Comment: @JakeMiller If you can't find an already implemented OAuth2 library you could avoid it and just issue your own JWTs. You can know who has the issued token by adding their username to the JSON. You'll know the user isn't lying because the signature is signed by you.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth 2.0 3 legged flow is mainly used to address a third-party application to gain resource owner access without sharing resource owner's credentials with the third party application.For example, a photo print application wants to access resource owner's (user) flicker account on behalf of resource owner without sharing the resource owner flicker account credentials.

In the traditional client-server authentication, you may consider to use OAuth 2.0 2 legged resource owner grant where OAuth 2.0 client application can request OAuth 2.0 Server to create OAuth Access Token. In this case, you can use JWT Token for OAuth Access Token. This flow is almost you have mentioned but only standard OAuth 2.0 resource owner request and response. Please refer resource owner request and response details at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2. If you use standard 2 legged OAuth flow, then client and server integration will be easy and interoperable.

If you don't want to support terminate(revoke) token operation, then you don't need to store the token in the database or any other place. In this case, the token can be self-expired but not terminated.
Even if you have a requirement for terminate token, then don't store the entire token and just store token uuid (random id) and set the token uuid in one of JWT Token Claim.